# how to implement emoji on android textview and edit text for starters

Tags: android, emoji

Please i want to know how to create my own custom emoji keyboard, is there any link i can go to inorder to do this, please forgive my question if it sounds too broad am new to android development

Comment: Check this https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-integrate-emojis-keyboard-app/

Comment: thanks i have checked that the only problem is that it is on android studio so i don't understand it, i want a tutorial that uses eclipse

Comment: Are you working on eclipse for android app development @vikki

Comment: Yes sir, an android social media app with php and mysqli as the backend,

Comment: yes i am working with eclipse @ Abhishek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the Library Url's you can use one of them

[image]
[image]

1. https://github.com/edsilfer/emoji-keyboard
2. https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon
3. https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon
4. https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard

Comment: Thanks alot, but how can i use them in eclipse

Comment: If you are using eclipse then you have to add jar file @vikki

Comment: how can i find the jar file, because its not included in the libraries

Comment: This site have lots of libraray you can include one of them

Comment: Welcome @vikki, Happy to help you

Comment: do you know the kind of design pattern facebook use in their android app, in the sense that it the first row of the custom list view is not the same as the others?

Comment: i don't know , i think they have their custom emoji @vikki

Comment: no, you didn't get the question, but i have done my research it is called "Heterogeneous listview" thanks tho. @Abhishek